# Regular Expressions - Understanding What It Means

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have this regular expression and I have to say what it means:

```
\++|[^|]\|*
```

Does it mean:

- 1 or more +
- [^|]      ? I don't know what this bit means.
- 0 or more |

What does the middle bit mean?

Comment: [Here is the explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nO3uN0/2).

Comment: Read the linked file, scroll down to: **Character Classes**.